# Change login user for GAE app

Tags: python, google-app-engine, authentication, account

My app has one page which only the admin can login to change the app settings. The thing is I have several google accounts. So when I use other account logged in such as gmail, then when I visit the admin page, the browser says:

```
Error: Forbidden
Your client does not have permission to get URL from this server.
```

There is no chance to change the logged in user and login again. It seems google share the user login cookies between their apps.

My question is how I can provide a page to let user to change the current login user?

I use python.

**My own solution:**

If the app.yaml has login:admin, then GAE will redirect the page to the above error anyway without going to the page handler's get method.
So just don't use the app.yaml login:admin setting and put

```
if users.is_current_user_admin():
    # normal code
else:
    self.redirect("http://admin.google.com")
```

Then the following page will let user change the account.

Comment: I found one way by myself.

Comment: put the answer above.